# XRDP doesnt connect to Azure VM suddenly

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, xrdp

[image]The RDP doesnt connect to the Azure Linux VM suddenly, the error is:
Password failed, error- problem connecting. 
This is the first time its happening. And  I tried restarting the VM, Resetting the password and also removing the credentials and adding again to the rdp. Please support on this.

Comment: Can anybody answer this please?

Comment: So I just fixed this problem, Hope it helps others: The moment u see connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 (or any other port). Take that port number, and allow that to the ufw using ( sudo ufw enable, Sudo ufw allow 3350 and sudo ufw allow 3389) . This worked for me. Hope it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered exactly the same issue on ubuntu 14.06 running on AWS today.
I checked the /var/log/apt/history.log and found out that the system updated the xrdp package automatically xrdp:amd64 (0.6.1-2, 0.6.1-2ubuntu0.1)

I downgraded the package and it now works again.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.6.1-2
```

Then, I decided to exclude xrdp from automatically being updated.

```
sudo apt-mark hold xrdp
```

xrdp set on hold.

Comment: I too downgraded it using that same command, but it din work. so i included port 3350 in the ufw, it worked. but now again same issue happening.

Comment: Whats happening when u hold xrdp? and how to release the hold. because my browser isnt working now.

Comment: If you hold a specific package, it will be excluded from an automatic update.
We can unhold the package by 
sudo apt-mark xrdp