# Sesman-Xvnc throws password failed with every user

Tags: windows, authentication, ubuntu-16.04, vnc, xrdp

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual machine that I use for log management. Since I created it, I use Sesman-Xvnc and has always been nice and easy to log in. However, after been on it for the last 3 weeks with on issues whatsoever, today I got to the office and it throws this error:

```
Connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display
Started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5912
tcp connected
security level is 2 (1 = none, 2 = standard)
password failed
error - problem connecting
```

I didn't changed my password, the machine was on all the time and I am able to log in via ssh with my user and password.

I have tried reinstalling the services with:

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

And then restarted the xrdp service with:

```
service xrdp restart
```

I have also created a new user but the results are the same; password failed.

Any ideas of how to sort this out?

Thank you very much familia. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I too have the same issue facing it since today, Have put up the issue here.

[XRDP doesnt connect to Azure VM suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126379/xrdp-doesnt-connect-to-azure-vm-suddenly)

I fixed it by allowing the port which it is trying to connect to sesman in the ufw:
The moment u see connecting to "sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350" (or any other port)  in the RDP, Take that port number, and allow that port to the ufw using 
These are the steps I used :
Downgrade ur xrdp using this :

[sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.6.1-2

and Hold the xrdp instance,

sudo apt-mark hold xrdp

Sudo ufw enable

Sudo ufw allow 3350 and

Sudo ufw allow 3389]

NB:You may use this cmd to see if its open:

sudo netstat -plnt | grep rdp

Perform these in the SSH window.

This worked for me. Hope it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and it seems to be caused by an automatic update of 'xrdp'.  Have a look to this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108550/xrdp-failed-problem-connecting-when-package-was-auto-updated

Comment: Thank you for your help Simon! I have tried editing the sesman.ini file as suggested but it didn't work for me. :(
I have also tried to reinstall vnc and xrdp but it didn't work either.
What claims my attention is that now, after the reinstall of both of the services, instead of connecting to 127.0.0.1 5912, it tries to do it to 5915. Would this be related to the issue?

Comment: Hi Eloy, we applied Jonathan Grant's answer (downgrade to the previous version).

Comment: Hi Simon, I tried to do so but it says that the version 0.6 is not found. :( 

E: Version '0.6.' for 'xrdp' was not found
E: Unable to locate package 1-2

This is being an absolute headache! :/

Comment: I could downgrade finally but no luck. :(